# Inserting random loop on the mesh to change topology

Tags: modeling, grease-pencil

How to insert random loop on the mesh ? It doesn't need to be circular.
I know how to use Crtl+R but I need to add more complex curve/loop streching to many faces.

Is it possible to draw the loop with grease pencil and then just attach it to mesh topology ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the topology of the model using the edge loop tool alone as CTRL R uses the existing topology of your model. Instead try using the knife tool to manually create your own topology.

Documentation for this can be found here.

https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/knife_subdivide.html

Make sure that when you use the knives tool you correct your topology as you are going as this can create ngons in areas that can be troublesome.

Comment: Link is broken.